# Persist ruby binding

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is there any way to persist ruby bindings ? I couldn't use marshal.dump. Doc says

> if the objects to be dumped include bindings, procedure or method objects, instances of class IO, or singleton objects, a TypeError will be raised.

We need to use same binding across multiple requests. How can I serialize/deserilaze ruby binding ?

Comment: How about a simple example, so those giving answers can demonstrate their code?

Comment: Does the word _requests_ mean HTTP requests?

Comment: *Why* would you want to? This sounds completely crazy to even attempt. If you wanted to persist the data and the binding you wouldn't have serialized it in the first place. Serializing has an implicit promise that you can de-serialize it in the future in a different process or a different machine and get the data back out. The binding will be completely gone by then.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of serializing a binding is in many ways incoherent, because a binding is intimately connected to the run-time stack; when you de-serialized the binding, should it re-create the stack, too?

That said, if you just want to get the *values* out of the binding, you could do it with something like this:

```
class Binding
  def values_for_serialization
    data = {
      locals: {},
      self: eval('self',self)
    }
    eval("local_variables",self).each do |lvar|
      data[:locals][lvar] = local_variable_get(lvar)
    end
    data
  end
end
```

You could then serialize the returned structure using `Marshal#dump`, `to_yaml`, or whatever.

De-serializing would work something like this:

```
class Binding
  def self.from_values(values)
    bind = values[:self].instance_exec { binding }
    values[:locals].each_pair do |lvar,value|
      bind.local_variable_set(lvar,value)
    end
    bind
   end
 end
```

But note that, while this would give you *a* binding that had an appropriate self object, and appropriate local variables, it wouldn't really be the *same* binding. For instance, if you tried to use this to serialize the top-level script binding, you could; and then in another script you could de-serialize it. But when you did, the local variables would *not* be available in that scripts top-level binding, they'd only be available in the binding object you'd created.